# What are the benefits of ORM lazy loading?

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate, orm

I'm researching data layer underpinnings for a new web-based reporting system and have spent a lot of time evaluating ORM's over the last few days.  That said, I've never dealt with "lazy loading" before and am confused at why its the default setting for LINQ queries in the Entity Framework.  It seems like it creates a lot of network traffic and unnecessarily tasks the database with additional queries that could otherwise be resolved with joins.

Can someone describe a scenario in which lazy loading would be beneficial?

Some meta:

The new system will be working against a database with hundreds of tables and many terabytes of data in a production environment with over 3,000 concurrent users on the system 24 hours a day.  They will be retrieving large datasets continuously.  Is it possible that an ORM just isn't the right solution for our needs, especially since the app will be web-based?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When we talk about lazy loading we are talking about Navigation Properties (how we follow foreign keys). What lazy loading will do for us is to populate the entity from a remote table as we attempt to access that entity. For example if we have a model like this

```
public class TestEntity
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public AnotherEntity RemoteEntity{get;set;}
}
```

And call the following

```
var something = WhateverContext.TestEntities.First().RemoteEntity;
```

We will get 2 database calls, one for `WhateverContext.TestEntities.First()` and one for loading the remote entity.

I'm a web guy, (and more specifically an MVC guy) and for web stuff I don't think there is ever a good reason for wanting to do this, One database call is always going to be quicker than two if we require the same set of data.

The situation where I think that lazy loading is actually worth considering is when you don't know when you do your first query if you will need the second entity at all. In my opinion this is much more relevant for windows applications where we have a user who is performing actions in real time (rather than stateless MVC where users are requesting whole pages at once). For example I think lazy loading shines when we have a list of data with a details link, then we don't load the details until the user decides they want to see them.

I don't feel this extends to paging, sorting and filtering, IMO there should be one specifically crafted database query per page of data you are displaying, which returns exactly the data set required to display that page.

In terms of your performance question, I feel that EF (or another ORM) can probably meet your needs here but you want to be careful with how you are retrieving large datasets due to the way EF tracks entities. Check out my [EF performance tuning cheat sheet](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/08/entity-framework-performance-cheat-sheet.html), and read up on [DetectChanges](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/05/entityframework-performance-and.html) and [AsNoTracking](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/04/entity-framework-and-asnotracking.html) if you do decide to use EF with large queries.

Comment: _I don't feel this extends to paging, sorting and filtering, IMO there should be one specifically crafted database query per page of data you are displaying..._ That's a web mindset, thick clients don't work that way. In addition that is a very static approach to data that is often times dynamic where allowing you to build the _subset_ of data on the fly is what the user is after.

Comment: @AaronMcIver I'm still not convinced, I'm not suggesting you shouldn't allow dynamic behavior on the client or that you should only do one query for a specific control. What I'm saying is that you should construct the query yourself so you do exactly one database call per user action, rather than an un-deterministic number of calls (which is essentially what you get with lazy loading). Also giving SQL a nice .orderby.where.skip.take query is probably going to execute much faster than trying to do the same in memory.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your object map, eager loading everything can create monster queries that take forever to execute. With NH, I'd suggest putting the work into defining fetching strategies rather than just turning lazy loading off altogether.

Answer (score 2):

A simple case is a result set of N records which you do not want to bring to the client at once. The benefit is that you are able to lazily load only what is needed for the clients demands, such as sorting, filtering, etc... An example would be a paging view where one could page through records and sort them accordingly, thus the client only needs N amount at a given time.

When you perform the LINQ query it translates that to SQL commands on the server side to provide only what is needed in the given context. It boils down to offloading work to the database and minimizing what you need to send back to the client.

Some will argue that ORM based lazy loading is wrong however that starts to move to semantics fairly quick and should be more about approach to design versus what is *right* and *wrong*.

Answer (score 2):

Most ORMs will give you the option, when you're building up your object selections, to say "don't be lazy, go ahead and join", so if you're worried about it from an efficiency perspective, don't be. You can make it work (usually).

There are 2 particular cases I know of where lazy loading helps:

1. Chaining commands
   What if you want to create a basic select, but then you want to run it through a sort and a filter function that's based on user input. You can simply pass the ORM object in, and attach the sort and filtering functionality to it. Instead of evaluating it each time, it only evaluates when it's actually used.
2. Avoiding huge, deep, highly-relational queries
   What if you just need the IDs of some related fields? If it loads lazily, you don't have to worry about it joining a whole bunch of data and tables that you don't need, potentially slowing down the query and overusing bandwidth. Of course, if you DID want everything else, then you'll need to be explicit, or you may run into a problem where it lazily runs a query for each detail record. Like I mentioned at the outset, that's easily overcome in any ORM worth using.